# Return string from Python to Shell script

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7, shell

I have Python code like:

```
x = sys.argv[1]
y = sys.argv[2]
i = sofe_def(x,y)

if i == 0:
    print "ERROR"
elif i == 1:
    return str(some_var1)
else:
    print "OOOps"
    num = input("Chose beetwen {0} and {1}".format(some_var2, some_var3))
    return str(num)
```

After I must execute this script in shell script and return string in shell variable, like:

```
VAR1="foo"
VAR2="bar"
RES=$(python test.py $VAR1 $VAR2)
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work. The way by stderr, stdout and stdin also doesn't work due to a lot of print and input() in code. So how I can resolve my issue? Thank you for answer

Comment: did you try just printing from your python command and setting that to a variable without doing any of the system exiting? e.g. `local_dir=$(python execute_tensorboard.py $1)`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That isn't even valid Python code; you are using `return` outside of a function. You don't wan't `return` here, just a `print` statement.

```
x, y = sys.argv[1:3]
i = sofe_def(x,y)

if i == 0:
    print >>sys.stderr, "ERROR"
elif i == 1:
    print str(some_var1)
else:
    print >>sys.stderr, "OOOps"
    print >>sys.stderr, "Choose between {0} and {1}".format(some_var2, some_var3)
    num = raw_input()
    print num
```

(Note some other changes:

1. Write your error messages to standard error, to avoid them being captured as well.
2. Use `raw_input`, not `input`, in Python 2.

)

Then your shell

```
VAR1="foo"
VAR2="bar"

RES=$(python test.py "$VAR1" "$VAR2")
```

should work. Unless you have a good reason *not* to, always quote parameter expansions.

Comment: Oh, the first of all I've forgotten about my Python script was pulled from def)) Thank you - it all works! But you missed `,` in `print >>sys.stderr "ERROR"`, `print >>sys.stderr, "ERROR"` and `    num =`raw_input("Choose between {0} and {1}".format(some_var2, some_var3))` also output text in result, I fixed it like: `print >>sys.stderr "Choose between {0} and {1}".format(some_var2, some_var3)`

Comment: For some reason, I was remembering `raw_input` printed its prompt to standard error; I'm probably confusing it with shell `read`. I was *definitely* confusing the `print` statement with Perl's `printf STDERR "Ooops\n"` (where no comma is allowed because Perl has nightmarish syntax).

Comment: this doesn't seem to work, it's saving the command I want to execute instead of its return value look: `(metalearning) brando~ ❯ VAR=%(python /Users/brando/ultimate-utils/ultimate-utils-project/execute_tensorboard.py /home/miranda9/data/logs/logs_Mar06_11-15-02_jobid_0_pid_3657/tb)
(metalearning) brando~ ❯ echo $VAR
%(python /Users/brando/ultimate-utils/ultimate-utils-project/execute_tensorboard.py /home/miranda9/data/logs/logs_Mar06_11-15-02_jobid_0_pid_3657/tb)`

Comment: @CharlieParker What shell are you using? Command substitution is `$(...)` in `bash`, not `%(...)`, though in that case I would expect some other error, not a full assignment to `VAR`.

Comment: Could we pass more than one string using multiple prints? If yes how should we obtain them in the bash file?

Answer (score 3):

Just use *print* instead of *return* - you bash snippet expects result on STDOUT.

Comment: can you be more precise on how the variable setting works? I tried:`(metalearning) brando~ ❯ VAR=python /Users/brando/ultimate-utils/ultimate-utils-project/execute_tensorboard.py /home/miranda9/data/logs/logs_Mar06_11-15-02_jobid_0_pid_3657/tb 
zsh: permission denied: /Users/brando/ultimate-utils/ultimate-utils-project/execute_tensorboard.py`
 but it doesn't work.